Header-only log-structured database
I'm seeking a code review for the ~2000 lines of code.
Makefile and tests are available at https://github.com/torrentg/logdb.
I would appreciate feedback on the following aspects:

Overall code structure and organization.
Error handling and robustness.
Efficiency and performance optimizations.
Compliance with best practices and coding standards.
Any potential memory leaks or undefined behaviour.

Currently simultaneous read/write is not supported.
My idea is to duplicate the file descriptors (one for reading
and another for writing) and use a mutex to guarantee data integrity.
Any other ideas?
I will be happy to know your opinions and objections.
Here is logdb.h:
#ifndef __LOGDB_H
#define __LOGDB_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

/**
 * Logdb is a simple database with the following characteristics:
 *   - Records have variable length (non-fixed record size)
 *   - Record identifier is a sequential number
 *   - Record are indexed by timestamp (monotonic non-decreasing field)
 *   - Only append function is supported (no update, no delete)
 *   - Data insertion flush data to disk
 *   - Automatic data recovery on catastrofic event
 *   - Records can be read (retrieved by seqnum)
 *   - Records can be searched by id (seqnum)
 *   - Records can be searched by timestamp
 *   - Rollback means to remove X records from top
 *   - Can be purged (removing X records from bottom)
 * 
 * Logdb is intended in the following case:
 *   - Need to persist sequentially ordered data
 *   - Most operations are write type
 *   - Data is rarely read or searched
 *   - Allows to revert last entries (rollback)
 *   - Eventually purge obsolete entries (purge)
 *   - Minimal memory footprint
 * 
 * dat file format
 * ---------------
 * 
 * Contains the database data.
 * 
 * @see struct ldb_header_dat_t
 * @see struct ldb_record_dat_t
 * 
 *      header      record1        data1       record2        data2
 * ┌──────┴──────┐┌─────┴─────┐┌─────┴─────┐┌─────┴─────┐┌─────┴─────┐...
 *   magic number   seqnum       raw bytes    seqnum       raw bytes
 *   format         timestamp                 timestamp
 *   etc.           lenght                    lenght
 * 
 * idx file format
 * ---------------
 * 
 * Used to search database entries.
 * If idx file does not exist, it is rebuild from the data.
 * 
 * @see struct ldb_header_idx_t
 * @see struct ldb_record_idx_t
 * 
 *      header      record1       record2
 * ┌──────┴──────┐┌─────┴─────┐┌─────┴─────┐...
 *   magic number   seqnum       seqnum
 *   format         timestamp    timestamp
 *   etc.           pos          pos
 * 
 * We can access directly any record by seqnum because:
 *  - we know the first seqnum in the db
 *  - we know the last seqnum in the db
 *  - idx header has fixed size
 *  - all idx records have same size
 *
 * We use the binary search method over the index records to search data by timestamp.
 * In all cases we rely on the system file caches to store data in memory.
 */

#define LDB_VERSION_MAJOR          0
#define LDB_VERSION_MINOR          1
#define LDB_VERSION_PATCH          0

#define LDB_OK                     0
#define LDB_ERR                   -1
#define LDB_ERR_ARG               -2
#define LDB_ERR_MEM               -3
#define LDB_ERR_PATH              -4
#define LDB_ERR_NAME              -5
#define LDB_ERR_OPEN_DAT          -6
#define LDB_ERR_READ_DAT          -7
#define LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT         -8
#define LDB_ERR_OPEN_IDX          -9
#define LDB_ERR_READ_IDX         -10
#define LDB_ERR_WRITE_IDX        -11
#define LDB_ERR_FMT_DAT          -12
#define LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX          -13
#define LDB_ERR_ENTRY_SEQNUM     -14
#define LDB_ERR_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP  -15
#define LDB_ERR_ENTRY_METADATA   -16
#define LDB_ERR_ENTRY_DATA       -17
#define LDB_ERR_NOT_FOUND        -18
#define LDB_ERR_TMP_FILE         -19

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef enum {
    LDB_SEARCH_LOWER,        // Returns the seqnum of the first entry having timestamp not less than the given value.
    LDB_SEARCH_UPPER         // Returns the seqnum of the first entry having timestamp greater than the given value.
} ldb_search_e;

typedef enum {
    LDB_STATUS_CLOSED = 0,
    LDB_STATUS_OPEN = 1
} ldb_status_e;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *path;
    char *dat_path;
    FILE *dat_fp;
    char *idx_path;
    FILE *idx_fp;
    uint64_t milestone;
    uint64_t first_seqnum;
    uint64_t first_timestamp;
    uint64_t last_seqnum;
    uint64_t last_timestamp;
    size_t dat_end;
    uint32_t format;
    char state;
} ldb_db_t;

typedef struct {
    uint64_t seqnum;
    uint64_t timestamp;
    uint32_t metadata_len;
    uint32_t data_len;
    char *metadata;
    char *data;
} ldb_entry_t;

typedef struct {
    uint64_t min_seqnum;
    uint64_t max_seqnum;
    uint64_t min_timestamp;
    uint64_t max_timestamp;
    uint64_t num_entries;
    uint64_t data_size;
    uint64_t index_size;
} ldb_stats_t;

/**
 * Returns ldb library version.
 * @return Library version (semantic version, ex. 1.0.4).
 */
const char * ldb_version(void);

/**
 * Returns the textual description of the ldb error code.
 * 
 * @param[in] errnum Code error.
 * @return Textual description.
 */
const char * ldb_strerror(int errnum);

/**
 * Deallocates the memory pointed by the entry.
 * 
 * Use this function to deallocate entries returned by ldb_read().
 * Update entry pointers to NULL and lengths to 0.
 * 
 * @param[in,out] entry Entry to dealloc data (if NULL does nothing).
 */
void ldb_free_entry(ldb_entry_t *entry);

/**
 * Deallocates the memory of an array of entries.
 * 
 * This is an utility function that calls ldb_free_entry() for
 * each array item.
 * 
 * @param[in] entries Array of entries (if NULL does nothing).
 * @param[in] len Number of entries.
 */
void ldb_free_entries(ldb_entry_t *entries, size_t len);

/**
 * Open a database.
 * 
 * Creates database files (dat+idx) if they not exists.
 * Update index file if incomplete (not flushed + crash).
 * Rebuild index file when corrupted or not found.
 * 
 * @param[in] path Directory where database files are located.
 * @param[in] name Database name (chars allowed: [a-ZA-Z_], max length = 32).
 * @param[in,out] obj Uninitialized database object.
 * @param[in] check Check database files (true|false).
 * @return Error code (0 = OK). On error db is closed properly (ldb_close not required).
 *         You can check errno value to get additional error details.
 */
int ldb_open(const char *path, const char *name, ldb_db_t *obj, bool check);

/**
 * Close a database.
 * 
 * Close open files and release allocated memory.
 * 
 * @param[in,out] obj Database to close.
 * @return Return code (0 = OK).
 */
int ldb_close(ldb_db_t *obj);

/**
 * Append entries to the database.
 * 
 * This function is not 'atomic'. Entries are appended sequentially. 
 * On error (ex. disk full) writed entries are flushed and remaining entries
 * are reported as not writed (see num return argument).
 * 
 * Seqnum values:
 *   - equals to 0 -> system assigns the sequential value.
 *   - distinct than 0 -> system check that it is the next value.
 * 
 * Timestamp values:
 *   - equals to 0: system assigns the current UTC epoch time (in millis).
 *   - distinct than 0 -> system check that is bigger or equal to previous timestamp.
 * 
 * File operations:
 *   - Data file is updated and flushed.
 *   - Index file is updated but not flushed.
 * 
 * Memory pointed by entries is not modified and can be deallocated after function call.
 * 
 * @param[in] obj Database to modify.
 * @param[in,out] entries Entries to append to the database. Memory pointed 
 *                  by each entry is not modified. Seqnum and timestamp
 *                  are updated if they have value 0.
 *                  User must reset pointers before reuse.
 * @param[in] len Number of entries to append.
 * @param[out] num Number of entries appended (can be NULL).
 * @return Error code (0 = OK).
 */
int ldb_append(ldb_db_t *obj, ldb_entry_t *entries, size_t len, size_t *num);

/**
 * Read num entries starting from seqnum (included).
 * 
 * @param[in] obj Database to use.
 * @param[in] seqnum Initial sequence number. It is set to seqnum if less than first seqnum.
 * @param[out] entries Array of entries (min length = len).
 *                  These entries are uninitialized (with NULL pointers) or entries 
 *                  previously initialized by ldb_read() function. In this case, the 
 *                  allocated memory is reused and will be reallocated if not enough.
 *                  Use ldb_free_entry() to dealloc returned entries.
 * @param[in] len Number of entries to read.
 * @param[out] num Number of entries read (can be NULL). If num less than 'len' means 
 *                  that last record was reached. Unused entries are signaled with 
 *                  seqnum = 0.
 * @return Error code (0 = OK). Can be returned 0 records when the db is empty or the given 
 *                  seqnum is greater than last db seqnum).
 */
int ldb_read(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum, ldb_entry_t *entries, size_t len, size_t *num);

/**
 * Return statistics between seqnum1 and seqnum2 (both included).
 * 
 * @param[in] obj Database to use.
 * @param[in] seqnum1 First sequence number.
 * @param[in] seqnum2 Second sequence number (greater or equal than seqnum1).
 * @param[out] stats Uninitialized statistics.
 * @return Error code (0 = OK).
 */
int ldb_stats(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum1, uint64_t seqnum2, ldb_stats_t *stats);

/**
 * Search the seqnum corresponding to the given timestamp.
 * 
 * Use the binary search algorithm over the index file.
 * 
 * @param[in] obj Database to use.
 * @param[in] ts Timestamp to search.
 * @param[in] mode Search mode.
 * @param[out] seqnum Resulting seqnum (0 = NOT_FOUND).
 * @return Error code (0 = OK).
 */
int ldb_search_by_ts(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t ts, ldb_search_e mode, uint64_t *seqnum);

/**
 * Remove all entries greater than seqnum.
 * 
 * File operations:
 *   - Index file is updated (zero'ed top-to-bottom) and flushed.
 *   - Data file is updated (zero'ed bottom-to-top) and flushed.
 * 
 * @param[in] obj Database to update.
 * @param[in] seqnum Sequence number from which records are removed (seqnum=0 removes all content).
 * @return Number of removed entries, or error if negative.
 */
int ldb_rollback(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum);

/**
 * Remove all entries less than seqnum.
 * 
 * This function is expensive because recreates the dat and idx files.
 * 
 * To prevent data loss in case of outage we do:
 *   - A tmp data file is created.
 *   - Preserved records are copied from dat file to tmp file.
 *   - Tmp, dat and idx are closed
 *   - Idx file is removed
 *   - Tmp file is renamed to dat
 *   - Dat file is opened
 *   - Idx file is rebuilt
 * 
 * @param[in] obj Database to update.
 * @param[in] seqnum Sequence number up to which records are removed.
 * @return Number of removed entries, or error if negative.
 */
int ldb_purge(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum);

/**
 * Update the milestone value.
 * 
 * Database file is flushed before function return.
 * 
 * @param[in] obj Database to use.
 * @param[in] seqnum Milestone value.
 * @return Error code (0 = OK).
 */
int ldb_update_milestone(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* __LOGDB_H */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#ifdef LDB_IMPL

#define LDB_EXT_DAT             ".dat"
#define LDB_EXT_IDX             ".idx"
#define LDB_EXT_TMP             ".tmp"
#define LDB_PATH_SEPARATOR      "/"
#define LDB_NAME_MAX_LENGTH     32 
#define LDB_TEXT_LEN            128  /* value multiple of 8 to preserve alignment */
#define LDB_TEXT_DAT            "\nThis is a ldb database dat file.\nDon't edit it.\n"
#define LDB_TEXT_IDX            "\nThis is a ldb database idx file.\nDon't edit it.\n"
#define LDB_MAGIC_NUMBER        0x62646C00
#define LDB_FORMAT_1            1

#define LDB_MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define LDB_MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define LDB_FREE(ptr) do { free(ptr); ptr = NULL; } while(0)

typedef struct {
    uint32_t magic_number;
    uint32_t format;
    char text[LDB_TEXT_LEN];
    uint64_t milestone;
} ldb_header_dat_t;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t magic_number;
    uint32_t format;
    char text[LDB_TEXT_LEN];
} ldb_header_idx_t;

typedef struct {
    uint64_t seqnum;
    uint64_t timestamp;
    uint32_t metadata_len;
    uint32_t data_len;
} ldb_record_dat_t;

typedef struct {
    uint64_t seqnum;
    uint64_t timestamp;
    uint64_t pos;
} ldb_record_idx_t;

const char * ldb_strerror(int errnum)
{
    switch(errnum)
    {
        case LDB_OK: return "Success";
        case LDB_ERR: return "Generic error";
        case LDB_ERR_ARG: return "Invalid argument";
        case LDB_ERR_MEM: return "Out of memory";
        case LDB_ERR_NAME: return "Invalid db name";
        case LDB_ERR_PATH: return "Invalid directory";
        case LDB_ERR_OPEN_DAT: return "Cannot open dat file";
        case LDB_ERR_READ_DAT: return "Error reading dat file";
        case LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT: return "Error writing to dat file";
        case LDB_ERR_OPEN_IDX: return "Cannot open idx file";
        case LDB_ERR_READ_IDX: return "Error reading idx file";
        case LDB_ERR_WRITE_IDX: return "Error writing to idx file";
        case LDB_ERR_FMT_DAT: return "Invalid dat file";
        case LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX: return "Invalid idx file";
        case LDB_ERR_ENTRY_SEQNUM: return "Broken sequence";
        case LDB_ERR_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP: return "Invalid timestamp";
        case LDB_ERR_ENTRY_METADATA: return "Metadata not found";
        case LDB_ERR_ENTRY_DATA: return "Data not found";
        case LDB_ERR_NOT_FOUND: return "No results";
        case LDB_ERR_TMP_FILE: return "Error creating temp file";
        default: return "Unknow error";
    }
}

static uint64_t ldb_get_millis(void)
{
    struct timeval tm = {0};
    gettimeofday(&tm, NULL);
    return (uint64_t)(tm.tv_sec * 1000 + tm.tv_usec / 1000);
}

static uint64_t ldb_clamp(uint64_t val, uint64_t lo, uint64_t hi)
{
    return (val < lo ? lo : (hi < val ? hi : val));
}

static bool ldb_is_valid_db(ldb_db_t *obj)
{
    return (obj &&
            obj->dat_fp && !feof(obj->dat_fp) && !ferror(obj->dat_fp) &&
            obj->idx_fp && !feof(obj->idx_fp) && !ferror(obj->idx_fp));
}

static int ldb_close_files(ldb_db_t *obj)
{
    if (!obj)
        return LDB_OK;

    int ret = LDB_OK;

    if (obj->idx_fp != NULL && fclose(obj->idx_fp) != 0)
        ret = LDB_ERR_WRITE_IDX;

    if (obj->dat_fp != NULL && fclose(obj->dat_fp) != 0)
        ret = LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT;

    obj->dat_fp = NULL;
    obj->idx_fp = NULL;
    obj->first_seqnum = 0;
    obj->first_timestamp = 0;
    obj->last_seqnum = 0;
    obj->last_timestamp = 0;
    obj->dat_end = 0;

    return ret;
}

static int ldb_free_db(ldb_db_t *obj)
{
    if (obj == NULL)
        return LDB_OK;

    int ret = ldb_close_files(obj);

    LDB_FREE(obj->name);
    LDB_FREE(obj->path);
    LDB_FREE(obj->dat_path);
    LDB_FREE(obj->idx_path);

    obj->milestone = 0;

    return ret;
}

void ldb_free_entry(ldb_entry_t *entry)
{
    if (entry == NULL)
        return;
    
    // ldb_alloc_entry() does only 1 mem allocation
    if (entry->metadata != NULL) {
        free(entry->metadata);
    }

    entry->metadata = NULL;
    entry->data = NULL;
    entry->metadata_len = 0;
    entry->data_len = 0;
}

void ldb_free_entries(ldb_entry_t *entries, size_t len)
{
    if (entries == NULL || len == 0)
        return;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        ldb_free_entry(entries + i);
}

// returns size adjusted to a multiple of sizeof(void*)
static size_t ldb_allocated_size(size_t size)
{
    size_t rem = size % sizeof(void *);
    return size + (rem == 0 ? 0 : sizeof(void *) - rem);
}

// try to reuse previous allocated memory
// otherwhise, free existent memory and does only 1 memory allocation
// both returned pointer are aligned to generic type (void*)
// returns false on error (allocation error)
static bool ldb_alloc_entry(ldb_entry_t *entry, uint32_t metadata_len, uint32_t data_len)
{
    if (entry == NULL)
        return false;

    if ((entry->metadata_len > 0 && entry->metadata == NULL) ||
        (entry->data_len > 0 && entry->data == NULL) ||
        (entry->metadata == NULL && entry->data != NULL))
     {
        assert(false);
        ldb_free_entry(entry);
    }

    size_t len1 = ldb_allocated_size(metadata_len);
    size_t len2 = ldb_allocated_size(data_len);
    assert((len1 + len2) % sizeof(void *) == 0);

    char *ptr = NULL;

    if (len1 + len2 <= ldb_allocated_size(entry->metadata_len) + ldb_allocated_size(entry->data_len)) {
        ptr = entry->metadata ? entry->metadata : (entry->data ? entry->data : NULL);
    }
    else {
        ldb_free_entry(entry);
        ptr = (char *) calloc((len1 + len2)/sizeof(void *), sizeof(void *));
        if (ptr == NULL)
            return false;
    }

    entry->metadata = ptr;
    entry->metadata_len = metadata_len;
    entry->data = ptr + (data_len == 0 ? 0 : len1);
    entry->data_len = data_len;

    return true;
}

static bool ldb_is_valid_path(const char *path)
{
    struct stat statbuf = {0};

    if (path == NULL)
        return false;

    if (*path == 0)  // case cwd (current working directory)
        return true;

    if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0)
        return false;

    if (!S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
        return false;

    if (access(path, R_OK) != 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

static bool ldb_is_valid_name(const char *name)
{
    if (!name || *name == 0)
        return false;

    const char *ptr = name;

    while (*ptr != 0 && (isalnum(*ptr) || *ptr == '_'))
        ptr++;

    return (*ptr == 0 && ptr - name < LDB_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
}

static char * ldb_create_filename(const char *path, const char *name, const char *ext)
{
    if (path == NULL || name == NULL || ext == NULL || strlen(name) == 0)
        return NULL;

    size_t len = strlen(path);
    bool path_sep_required = (len > 0 && path[len -1] != LDB_PATH_SEPARATOR[0]);

    len = strlen(path) + 1 + strlen(name) + strlen(ext) + 1;
    char *filepath = (char *) calloc(len, sizeof(char));

    if (filepath == NULL)
        return NULL;

    snprintf(filepath, len, "%s%s%s%s", 
             path,
             (path_sep_required ? LDB_PATH_SEPARATOR : ""),
             name,
             ext);

    return filepath;
}

static bool ldb_create_file_dat(const char *path)
{
    assert(path);

    if (access(path, F_OK) == 0)
        return false;

    bool ret = true;

    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return false;

    ldb_header_dat_t header = {
        .magic_number = LDB_MAGIC_NUMBER,
        .text = {0},
        .format = LDB_FORMAT_1,
        .milestone = 0
    };

    strncpy(header.text, LDB_TEXT_DAT, sizeof(header.text));

    if (fwrite(&header, sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t), 1, fp) != 1)
        ret = false;

    if (fclose(fp) != 0)
        ret = false;

    return ret;
}

static bool ldb_create_file_idx(const char *path)
{
    assert(path);

    if (access(path, F_OK) == 0)
        return false;

    bool ret = true;

    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return false;

    ldb_header_idx_t header = {
        .magic_number = LDB_MAGIC_NUMBER,
        .text = {0},
        .format = LDB_FORMAT_1
    };

    strncpy(header.text, LDB_TEXT_IDX, sizeof(header.text));

    if (fwrite(&header, sizeof(ldb_header_idx_t), 1, fp) != 1)
        ret = false;

    if (fclose(fp) != 0)
        ret = false;

    return ret;
}

// Returns file size preserving current file position
// Returns 0 on error
static size_t ldb_get_file_size(FILE *fp)
{
    assert(fp);
    assert(!ferror(fp));

    long pos = ftell(fp);
    if (pos < 0)
        return 0;

    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) != 0)
        return 0;

    long len = ftell(fp);

    if (fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        return 0;

    return (size_t)(len < 0 ? 0 : len);
}

// Set zero's from pos until the end of the file.
// Does not update file if already zeroized.
// Preserve current file position.
// Flush file.
// On error return false, otherwhise returns true.
static bool ldb_zeroize(FILE *fp, size_t pos)
{
    assert(fp);
    assert(!feof(fp));
    assert(!ferror(fp));

    char c = 0;
    bool ret = false;
    size_t cur_pos = pos;
    size_t max_pos = ldb_get_file_size(fp);
    const char buf[4096] = {0};

    if (max_pos < pos)
        goto LDB_ZEROIZE_END;

    if (fseek(fp, (long) pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        goto LDB_ZEROIZE_END;

    for (cur_pos = pos; cur_pos < max_pos; cur_pos++)
    {
        if (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, fp) != 1)
            goto LDB_ZEROIZE_END;

        if (c == 0)
            continue;

        if (fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR) != 0)
            goto LDB_ZEROIZE_END;

        break;
    }

    // case already zeroized
    if (c == 0) {
        ret = true;
        goto LDB_ZEROIZE_END;
    }

    for (; cur_pos < max_pos; cur_pos += sizeof(buf))
        if (fwrite(buf, LDB_MIN((long) max_pos - (long) cur_pos, (long) sizeof(buf)), 1, fp) != 1)
            goto LDB_ZEROIZE_END;

    if (fflush(fp) != 0)
        goto LDB_ZEROIZE_END;

    ret = true;

LDB_ZEROIZE_END:
    fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET);
    assert(!feof(fp) && !ferror(fp));
    return ret;
}

// Copy file1 content in range [pos0,pos1] to file2 at pos2.
// Preserve current file positions.
// Flush destination file.
// On error return false, otherwhise returns true.
static bool ldb_copy_file(FILE *fp1, size_t pos0, size_t pos1, FILE *fp2, size_t pos2)
{
    assert(fp1);
    assert(!feof(fp1));
    assert(!ferror(fp1));
    assert(fp2);
    assert(!feof(fp2));
    assert(!ferror(fp2));
    assert(pos0 <= pos1);

    bool ret = false;
    char buf[4096] = {0};
    size_t orig1 = ftell(fp1);
    size_t orig2 = ftell(fp2);
    size_t len1 = ldb_get_file_size(fp1);
    size_t len2 = ldb_get_file_size(fp2);

    if (pos0 > pos1 || pos1 > len1 || pos2 > len2)
        return false;

    if (pos0 == pos1)
        return true;

    if (fseek(fp1, (long) pos0, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        goto LDB_COPY_FILE_END;

    if (fseek(fp2, (long) pos2, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        goto LDB_COPY_FILE_END;

    for (size_t pos = pos0; pos < pos1; pos += sizeof(buf))
    {
        size_t num_bytes = LDB_MIN((long) pos1 - (long) pos, (long) sizeof(buf));

        if (fread(buf, 1, num_bytes, fp1) != num_bytes)
            goto LDB_COPY_FILE_END;

        if (fwrite(buf, num_bytes, 1, fp2) != 1)
            goto LDB_COPY_FILE_END;
    }

    if (fflush(fp2) != 0)
        goto LDB_COPY_FILE_END;

    ret = true;

LDB_COPY_FILE_END:
    fseek(fp1, orig1, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(fp2, orig2, SEEK_SET);
    assert(!feof(fp1) && !ferror(fp1));
    assert(!feof(fp2) && !ferror(fp2));
    return ret;
}

static int ldb_append_entry_dat(ldb_db_t *obj, ldb_entry_t *entry)
{
    assert(obj);
    assert(entry);
    assert(obj->dat_fp);
    assert(!feof(obj->dat_fp));
    assert(!ferror(obj->dat_fp));

    if (entry->metadata_len != 0 && entry->metadata == NULL)
    return LDB_ERR_ENTRY_METADATA;

    if (entry->data_len != 0 && entry->data == NULL)
        return LDB_ERR_ENTRY_DATA;

    if (obj->last_seqnum != 0 && entry->seqnum != obj->last_seqnum + 1)
        return LDB_ERR_ENTRY_SEQNUM;
                                                                                                                                 
    if (entry->timestamp < obj->last_timestamp)
        return LDB_ERR_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP;

    ldb_record_dat_t record = {
        .seqnum = entry->seqnum,
        .timestamp = entry->timestamp,
        .metadata_len = entry->metadata_len,
        .data_len = entry->data_len
    };

    if (fseek(obj->dat_fp, obj->dat_end, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        return LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT;

    if (fwrite(&record, sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t), 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1)
        return LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT;

    if (record.metadata_len)
        if (fwrite(entry->metadata, sizeof(char), record.metadata_len, obj->dat_fp) != record.metadata_len)
            return LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT;

    if (record.data_len)
        if (fwrite(entry->data, sizeof(char), record.data_len, obj->dat_fp) != record.data_len)
            return LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT;

    if (obj->first_seqnum == 0) {
        obj->first_seqnum = entry->seqnum;
        obj->first_timestamp = entry->timestamp;
    }

    obj->last_seqnum = entry->seqnum;
    obj->last_timestamp = entry->timestamp;
    obj->dat_end = (size_t) ftell(obj->dat_fp);

    return LDB_OK;
}

static int ldb_read_record_dat(ldb_db_t *obj, size_t pos, ldb_record_dat_t *record)
{
    assert(obj);
    assert(record);
    assert(obj->dat_fp);
    assert(!feof(obj->dat_fp));
    assert(!ferror(obj->dat_fp));

    if (fseek(obj->dat_fp, pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        return LDB_ERR_READ_DAT;

    if (fread(record, sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t), 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1)
        return LDB_ERR_READ_DAT;

    if (record->seqnum < obj->first_seqnum || obj->last_seqnum < record->seqnum)
        return LDB_ERR;

    return LDB_OK;
}

static int ldb_read_entry_dat(ldb_db_t *obj, size_t pos, ldb_entry_t *entry)
{
    assert(obj);
    assert(entry);
    assert(obj->dat_fp);
    assert(!feof(obj->dat_fp));
    assert(!ferror(obj->dat_fp));

    int rc = 0;
    ldb_record_dat_t record = {0};

    if ((rc = ldb_read_record_dat(obj, pos, &record)) != LDB_OK)
        return rc;

    if (!ldb_alloc_entry(entry, record.metadata_len, record.data_len))
        return LDB_ERR_MEM;

    if (record.metadata_len) {
        assert(entry->metadata != NULL);
        if (fread(entry->metadata, record.metadata_len, 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1)
            return LDB_ERR_READ_DAT;
    }

    if (record.data_len) {
        assert(entry->data != NULL);
        if (fread(entry->data, record.data_len, 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1)
            return LDB_ERR_READ_DAT;
    }

    entry->seqnum = record.seqnum;
    entry->timestamp = record.timestamp;

    return LDB_OK;
}

static size_t ldb_get_pos_idx(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum)
{
    assert(obj);
    assert(obj->first_seqnum <= seqnum);
    assert(seqnum <= obj->last_seqnum);

    size_t diff = (obj->first_seqnum == 0 ? 0 : seqnum - obj->first_seqnum);
    return sizeof(ldb_header_idx_t) + diff * sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t);
}

static int ldb_append_record_idx(ldb_db_t *obj, ldb_record_idx_t *record)
{
    assert(obj);
    assert(record);
    assert(obj->idx_fp);
    assert(!feof(obj->idx_fp));
    assert(!ferror(obj->idx_fp));
    assert(obj->first_seqnum <= obj->last_seqnum);

    if (record->seqnum != obj->last_seqnum) {
        assert(false);
        return LDB_ERR;
    }

    size_t pos = ldb_get_pos_idx(obj, record->seqnum);

    if (fseek(obj->idx_fp, (long) pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        return LDB_ERR_READ_IDX;

    if (fwrite(record, sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t), 1, obj->idx_fp) != 1)
        return LDB_ERR_WRITE_IDX;

    return LDB_OK;
}

static int ldb_read_record_idx(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum, ldb_record_idx_t *record)
{
    assert(obj);
    assert(record);
    assert(seqnum > 0);

    if (seqnum == obj->first_seqnum) {
        record->seqnum = obj->first_seqnum;
        record->timestamp = obj->first_timestamp;
        record->pos = sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t);
        return LDB_OK;
    }

    if (obj->first_seqnum == 0 || seqnum < obj->first_seqnum || obj->last_seqnum < seqnum)
        return LDB_ERR;

    size_t pos = ldb_get_pos_idx(obj, seqnum);

    if (fseek(obj->idx_fp, (long) pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        return LDB_ERR_READ_IDX;

    if (fread(record, sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t), 1, obj->idx_fp) != 1)
        return LDB_ERR_READ_IDX;

    if (record->seqnum != seqnum)
        return LDB_ERR;

    return LDB_OK;
}

#define exit_function(errnum) do { ret = errnum; goto LDB_OPEN_FILE_DAT_END; } while(0)

/**
 * pre-conditions:
 *   - obj->dat_fp == NULL
 *   - obj->idx_fp == NULL
 *
 * post-conditions (OK)
 *   - obj->dat_fp = set
 *   - obj->format = set
 *   - obj->first_seqnum = set (0 if no data)
 *   - obj->first_timestamp = set
 * 
 * post-conditions (KO)
 *   - obj->dat_fp = NULL
 */
static int ldb_open_file_dat(ldb_db_t *obj, bool check)
{
    assert(obj);
    assert(obj->dat_fp == NULL);
    assert(obj->idx_fp == NULL);

    int ret = LDB_OK;
    ldb_header_dat_t header = {0};
    ldb_record_dat_t record = {0};
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t len = 0;

    obj->first_seqnum = 0;
    obj->first_timestamp = 0;
    obj->last_seqnum = 0;
    obj->last_timestamp = 0;
    obj->dat_end = sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t);

    obj->dat_fp = fopen(obj->dat_path, "r+");

    if (obj->dat_fp == NULL)
        return LDB_ERR_OPEN_DAT;

    len = ldb_get_file_size(obj->dat_fp);

    if (fread(&header, sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t), 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_DAT);

    pos += sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t);

    if (header.magic_number != LDB_MAGIC_NUMBER) 
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_DAT);

    if (header.format != LDB_FORMAT_1)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_DAT);

    obj->format = header.format;
    obj->milestone = header.milestone;

    if (pos == len)
    {
        // there is no first entry
    }
    else if (pos + sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t) > len)
    {
        if (!ldb_zeroize(obj->dat_fp, pos))
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT);
    }
    else
    {
        // read first entry
        if (fread(&record, sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t), 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1) 
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_DAT);

        // case first record is empty
        if (record.seqnum == 0) {
            memset(&record, 0x00, sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t));
            if (!ldb_zeroize(obj->dat_fp, pos))
                exit_function(LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT);
        }

        pos += sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t);
        pos += record.metadata_len + record.data_len;

        if (pos > len)
        {
            pos -= sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t);
            pos -= record.metadata_len + record.data_len;
            memset(&record, 0x00, sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t));
            if (!ldb_zeroize(obj->dat_fp, pos))
                exit_function(LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT);
        }
        else
        {
            if (fseek(obj->dat_fp, (long) pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
                exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_DAT);
        }

        obj->first_seqnum = record.seqnum;
        obj->first_timestamp = record.timestamp;
    }

    if (!check) {
        return LDB_OK;
    }

    obj->last_seqnum = record.seqnum;
    obj->last_timestamp = record.timestamp;

    while (pos + sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t) <= len)
    {
        if (fread(&record, sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t), 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1) 
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_DAT);

        // case record removed (rollback)
        if (record.seqnum == 0 || obj->first_seqnum == 0)
            break;

        pos += sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t);

        if (record.seqnum != obj->last_seqnum + 1) 
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_DAT);

        if (record.timestamp < obj->last_timestamp)
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_DAT);

        pos += record.metadata_len + record.data_len;

        if (pos > len) {
            // repair: remove offending record
            pos -= sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t);
            pos -= record.metadata_len + record.data_len;
            break;
        }

        if (fseek(obj->dat_fp, (long) pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_DAT);

        obj->last_seqnum = record.seqnum;
        obj->last_timestamp = record.timestamp;
    }

    if (!ldb_zeroize(obj->dat_fp, pos))
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT);

    return LDB_OK;

LDB_OPEN_FILE_DAT_END:
    ldb_close_files(obj);
    return ret;
}

#undef exit_function
#define exit_function(errnum) do { ret = errnum; goto LDB_OPEN_FILE_IDX_END; } while(0)

/**
 * pre-conditions:
 *   - obj->dat_fp != NULL
 *   - obj->idx_fp == NULL
 *   - obj->first_seqnum = set (0 if no data)
 *   - obj->first_timestamp = set
 *   - obj->format = set
 *
 * post-conditions (OK)
 *   - obj->dat_fp = set
 *   - obj->idx_fp = set
 *   - obj->first_seqnum = set (0 if no data)
 *   - obj->first_timestamp = set
 *   - obj->last_seqnum = set (0 if no data)
 *   - obj->last_timestamp = set
 *   - obj->dat_end = set
 * 
 * post-conditions (KO)
 *   - obj->idx_fp = NULL
 */
static int ldb_open_file_idx(ldb_db_t *obj, bool check)
{
    assert(obj);
    assert(obj->idx_fp == NULL);
    assert(obj->dat_fp != NULL);
    assert(!ferror(obj->dat_fp));

    int ret = LDB_OK;
    ldb_header_idx_t header = {0};
    ldb_record_idx_t record_0 = {0};
    ldb_record_idx_t record_n = {0};
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t len = 0;

    obj->idx_fp = fopen(obj->idx_path, "r+");

    if (obj->idx_fp == NULL)
        return LDB_ERR_OPEN_IDX;

    len = ldb_get_file_size(obj->idx_fp);

    if (fread(&header, sizeof(ldb_header_idx_t), 1, obj->idx_fp) != 1)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

    pos += sizeof(ldb_header_idx_t);

    if (header.magic_number != LDB_MAGIC_NUMBER)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

    if (header.format != LDB_FORMAT_1)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

    if (header.format != obj->format)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

    if (pos + sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t) <= len)
    {
        // read first entry
        if (fread(&record_0, sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t), 1, obj->idx_fp) != 1) 
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_IDX);

        pos += sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t);

        if (record_0.seqnum != obj->first_seqnum)
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

        if (record_0.timestamp != obj->first_timestamp)
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

        if (record_0.seqnum != 0 && record_0.pos != sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t))
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);
    }

    record_n = record_0;

    // read last record distinct than 0
    if (record_0.seqnum == 0)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
    else if (check)
    {
        ldb_record_idx_t aux = {0};
        ldb_record_dat_t record_dat = {0};

        while (pos + sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t) <= len)
        {
            if (fread(&aux, sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t), 1, obj->idx_fp) != 1) 
                exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_IDX);

            if (aux.seqnum == 0)
                break;

            pos += sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t);

            if (aux.seqnum != record_n.seqnum + 1 || aux.timestamp < record_n.timestamp || aux.pos < record_n.pos + sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t))
                exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

            if (fseek(obj->dat_fp, (long) aux.pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
                exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_IDX);

            if (fread(&record_dat, sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t), 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1) 
                exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_IDX);

            if (aux.seqnum != record_dat.seqnum || aux.timestamp != record_dat.timestamp)
                exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

            record_n = aux;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // search last valid position
        long rem = (len - sizeof(ldb_header_idx_t)) % sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t);
        if (fseek(obj->idx_fp, -rem, SEEK_END) != 0)
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_IDX);

        pos = (size_t)(len) - (size_t)(rem);

        // move backard until last record distinct than 0 (not rollbacked)
        while (pos > sizeof(ldb_header_idx_t))
        {
            if (fseek(obj->idx_fp, pos - sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t), SEEK_SET) != 0)
                exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_IDX);

            if (fread(&record_n, sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t), 1, obj->idx_fp) != 1) 
                exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_IDX);

            if (record_n.seqnum != 0)
                break;

            pos -= sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t);
        }
    }

    // at this point pos is just after the last record distinct than 0
    if (fseek(obj->idx_fp, (long) pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_IDX);

    if (!ldb_zeroize(obj->idx_fp, pos))
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_WRITE_IDX);

    // case idx with no records
    if (record_0.seqnum == 0)
    {
        // adding first dat record (if any)
        if (obj->first_seqnum != 0)
        {
            record_0.seqnum = obj->first_seqnum;
            record_0.timestamp = obj->first_timestamp;
            record_0.pos = sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t);

            obj->last_seqnum = obj->first_seqnum;
            obj->last_timestamp = obj->first_timestamp;

            if ((ret = ldb_append_record_idx(obj, &record_0)) != LDB_OK)
                goto LDB_OPEN_FILE_IDX_END;

            record_n = record_0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // check record_n content
        size_t diff = record_n.seqnum - record_0.seqnum;

        if (record_n.seqnum < record_0.seqnum || record_n.timestamp < record_0.timestamp)
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

        if (pos != sizeof(ldb_header_idx_t) + (diff + 1) * sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t))
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

        if (record_n.pos < sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t) + (diff + 1) * sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t))
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

        obj->last_seqnum = record_n.seqnum;
        obj->last_timestamp = record_n.timestamp;
    }

    // case no data
    if (obj->first_seqnum == 0) {
        obj->dat_end = sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t);
        return LDB_OK;
    }

    // read last record (dat)
    ldb_record_dat_t record_dat = {0};

    pos = record_n.pos;
    len = ldb_get_file_size(obj->dat_fp);

    if (fseek(obj->dat_fp, (long) pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_DAT);

    if (pos + sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t) > len)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

    if (fread(&record_dat, sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t), 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1) 
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_DAT);

    pos += sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t);

    if (record_dat.seqnum != record_n.seqnum || record_dat.timestamp != record_n.timestamp)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

    pos += record_dat.metadata_len + record_dat.data_len;

    if (pos > len)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX);

    if (fseek(obj->dat_fp, (long) pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_DAT);

    obj->dat_end = pos;

    // add unflushed dat records (if any)
    while (pos + sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t) <= len)
    {
        if (fread(&record_dat, sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t), 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1) 
           exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_DAT);
        
        if (record_dat.seqnum == 0)
            break;

        pos += sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t);

        if (record_dat.seqnum != obj->last_seqnum + 1)
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_DAT);

        if (record_dat.timestamp < obj->last_timestamp)
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_FMT_DAT);

        pos += record_dat.metadata_len + record_dat.data_len;

        if (pos > len) {
            // repair: remove ofending record
            pos -= sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t);
            pos -= record_dat.metadata_len + record_dat.data_len;
            break;
        }

        if (fseek(obj->dat_fp, (long) pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_READ_DAT);

        record_n.seqnum = record_dat.seqnum;
        record_n.timestamp = record_dat.timestamp;
        record_n.pos += obj->dat_end;

        obj->last_seqnum = record_dat.seqnum;
        obj->last_timestamp = record_dat.timestamp;
        obj->dat_end = (size_t) ftell(obj->dat_fp);

        if ((ret = ldb_append_record_idx(obj, &record_n)) != LDB_OK)
            goto LDB_OPEN_FILE_IDX_END;

        assert(obj->dat_end == pos);
    }

    if (!ldb_zeroize(obj->dat_fp, pos))
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT);

    return LDB_OK;

LDB_OPEN_FILE_IDX_END:
    fclose(obj->idx_fp);
    obj->idx_fp = NULL;
    return ret;
}

#undef exit_function

const char * ldb_version(void)
{
    static char version_str[32] = {0};

    if (version_str[0] == 0) {
        snprintf(version_str, sizeof(version_str), "%d.%d.%d", 
                LDB_VERSION_MAJOR, LDB_VERSION_MINOR, LDB_VERSION_PATCH);
    }

    return version_str;
}

#define exit_function(errnum) do { ret = errnum; goto LDB_OPEN_END; } while(0)

int ldb_open(const char *path, const char *name, ldb_db_t *obj, bool check)
{
    if (path == NULL || name == NULL || obj == NULL)
        return LDB_ERR_ARG;

    if (!ldb_is_valid_path(path))
        return LDB_ERR_PATH;

    if (!ldb_is_valid_name(name))
        return  LDB_ERR_NAME;

    int ret = LDB_OK;

    memset(obj, 0x00, sizeof(ldb_db_t));

    obj->name = strdup(name);
    obj->path = strdup(path);
    obj->dat_path = ldb_create_filename(path, name, LDB_EXT_DAT);
    obj->idx_path = ldb_create_filename(path, name, LDB_EXT_IDX);
    obj->dat_end = sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t);

    if (!obj->name || !obj->path || !obj->dat_path || !obj->idx_path)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_MEM);

    // case dat file not exist
    if (access(obj->dat_path, F_OK) != 0)
    {
        remove(obj->idx_path);

        if (!ldb_create_file_dat(obj->dat_path))
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_OPEN_DAT);
    }

    // case dat file not exist
    if (access(obj->idx_path, F_OK) != 0)
    {
        if (!ldb_create_file_idx(obj->idx_path))
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_OPEN_IDX);
    }

    if ((ret = ldb_open_file_dat(obj, check)) != LDB_OK)
        goto LDB_OPEN_END;

    ret = ldb_open_file_idx(obj, check);
    if (ret == LDB_ERR_READ_IDX || ret == LDB_ERR_WRITE_IDX || ret == LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX)
    {
        // try to rebuild the index file
        remove(obj->idx_path);

        if (!ldb_create_file_idx(obj->idx_path))
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_OPEN_IDX);

        if ((ret = ldb_open_file_idx(obj, check)) != LDB_OK)
            goto LDB_OPEN_END;
    }

    assert(!feof(obj->dat_fp));
    assert(!feof(obj->idx_fp));
    assert(!ferror(obj->dat_fp));
    assert(!ferror(obj->idx_fp));

    return LDB_OK;

LDB_OPEN_END:
    ldb_free_db(obj);
    return ret;
}

#undef exit_function

int ldb_close(ldb_db_t *obj)
{
    return ldb_free_db(obj);
}

int ldb_append(ldb_db_t *obj, ldb_entry_t *entries, size_t len, size_t *num)
{
    if (!ldb_is_valid_db(obj))
        return LDB_ERR;

    if (!entries)
        return LDB_ERR_ARG;

    if (num != NULL)
        *num = 0;

    size_t i;
    int ret = LDB_OK;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (entries[i].seqnum == 0)
            entries[i].seqnum = obj->last_seqnum + 1;

        if (entries[i].timestamp == 0) 
            entries[i].timestamp = LDB_MAX(ldb_get_millis(), obj->last_timestamp);

        ldb_record_idx_t record_idx = {
            .seqnum = entries[i].seqnum,
            .timestamp = entries[i].timestamp,
            .pos = obj->dat_end
        };

        if ((ret = ldb_append_entry_dat(obj, &entries[i])) != LDB_OK)
            break;

        if ((ret = ldb_append_record_idx(obj, &record_idx)) != LDB_OK)
            break;

        if (num != NULL)
            (*num)++;
    }

    if (i > 0 && fflush(obj->dat_fp) != 0)
        ret = LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT;

    return ret;
}

int ldb_read(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum, ldb_entry_t *entries, size_t len, size_t *num)
{
    if (!ldb_is_valid_db(obj))
        return LDB_ERR;

    if (!entries)
        return LDB_ERR_ARG;

    if (num != NULL)
        *num = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        entries[i].seqnum = 0;
        entries[i].timestamp = 0;
    }

    if (seqnum < obj->first_seqnum)
        seqnum = obj->first_seqnum;

    if (seqnum == 0 || seqnum < obj->first_seqnum || seqnum > obj->last_seqnum)
        return LDB_OK;

    int rc = 0;
    ldb_record_idx_t record_idx = {0};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len && seqnum <= obj->last_seqnum; i++)
    {
        if ((rc = ldb_read_record_idx(obj, seqnum, &record_idx)) != LDB_OK)
            return rc;

        if ((rc = ldb_read_entry_dat(obj, record_idx.pos, entries + i)) != LDB_OK)
            return rc;

        if (entries[i].seqnum != seqnum)
            return LDB_ERR;

        seqnum++;

        if (num != NULL)
            (*num)++;
    }

    return LDB_OK;
}

int ldb_stats(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum1, uint64_t seqnum2, ldb_stats_t *stats)
{
    if (!ldb_is_valid_db(obj))
        return LDB_ERR;

    if (seqnum2 < seqnum1 || stats == NULL)
        return LDB_ERR_ARG;

    memset(stats, 0x00, sizeof(ldb_stats_t));

    if (obj->first_seqnum == 0) {
        return LDB_OK;
    }

    seqnum1 = ldb_clamp(seqnum1, obj->first_seqnum, obj->last_seqnum);
    seqnum2 = ldb_clamp(seqnum2, obj->first_seqnum, obj->last_seqnum);

    int rc = LDB_ERR;
    ldb_record_idx_t record1 = {0};
    ldb_record_idx_t record2 = {0};
    ldb_record_dat_t record_dat = {0};

    if ((rc = ldb_read_record_idx(obj, seqnum1, &record1)) != LDB_OK)
        return rc;

    if ((rc = ldb_read_record_idx(obj, seqnum2, &record2)) != LDB_OK)
        return rc;

    if (record2.pos < record1.pos + (record2.seqnum - record1.seqnum) * sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t))
        return LDB_ERR;

    if ((rc = ldb_read_record_dat(obj, record2.pos, &record_dat)) != LDB_OK)
        return rc;

    if (record_dat.seqnum != seqnum2)
        return LDB_ERR;

    stats->min_seqnum = record1.seqnum;
    stats->min_timestamp = record1.timestamp;
    stats->max_seqnum = record2.seqnum;
    stats->max_timestamp = record2.timestamp;
    stats->num_entries = seqnum2 - seqnum1 + 1;
    stats->index_size = sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t) * stats->num_entries;
    stats->data_size = record2.pos - record1.pos + sizeof(ldb_record_dat_t) +
                       record_dat.metadata_len + record_dat.data_len;

    return LDB_OK;
}

int ldb_search_by_ts(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t timestamp, ldb_search_e mode, uint64_t *seqnum)
{
    if (!ldb_is_valid_db(obj))
        return LDB_ERR;

    if (seqnum == NULL)
        return LDB_ERR_ARG;

    if (mode != LDB_SEARCH_LOWER && mode != LDB_SEARCH_UPPER)
        return LDB_ERR_ARG;

    *seqnum = 0;

    if (obj->first_seqnum == 0)
        return LDB_ERR_NOT_FOUND;

    if (mode == LDB_SEARCH_LOWER && obj->last_timestamp < timestamp)
        return LDB_ERR_NOT_FOUND;

    if (mode == LDB_SEARCH_UPPER && obj->last_timestamp <= timestamp)
        return LDB_ERR_NOT_FOUND;

    if (mode == LDB_SEARCH_LOWER && timestamp <= obj->first_timestamp) {
        *seqnum = obj->first_seqnum;
        return LDB_OK;
    }

    if (mode == LDB_SEARCH_UPPER && timestamp < obj->first_timestamp) {
        *seqnum = obj->first_seqnum;
        return LDB_OK;
    }

    int rc = 0;
    ldb_record_idx_t record = {0};
    uint64_t sn1 = obj->first_seqnum;
    uint64_t sn2 = obj->last_seqnum;
    uint64_t ts1 = obj->first_timestamp;
    uint64_t ts2 = obj->last_timestamp;

    assert(ts1 <= timestamp && timestamp <= ts2);

    while (sn1 + 1 < sn2 && ts1 != ts2)
    {
        uint64_t sn = (sn1 + sn2) / 2;

        if ((rc = ldb_read_record_idx(obj, sn, &record)) != LDB_OK)
            return rc;

        uint64_t ts = record.timestamp;

        if (ts < timestamp) {
            sn1 = sn;
            ts1 = ts;
        }
        else if (timestamp < ts || mode == LDB_SEARCH_LOWER) {
            sn2 = sn;
            ts2 = ts;
        }
        else {
            sn1 = sn;
            ts1 = ts;
        }
    }

    *seqnum = sn2;

    return LDB_OK;
}

int ldb_rollback(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum)
{
    if (!ldb_is_valid_db(obj))
        return LDB_ERR;

    // case nothing to rollback
    if (obj->last_seqnum <= seqnum)
        return 0;

    int rc = LDB_ERR;
    int removed_entries = obj->last_seqnum - LDB_MAX(seqnum, obj->first_seqnum - 1);
    uint64_t csn = obj->last_seqnum;
    ldb_record_idx_t record_idx = {0};
    size_t dat_end_new = sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t);
    uint64_t last_timestamp_new = 0;

    if (seqnum >= obj->first_seqnum)
    {
        if ((rc = ldb_read_record_idx(obj, seqnum, &record_idx)) != LDB_OK)
            return rc;

        last_timestamp_new = record_idx.timestamp;

        if ((rc = ldb_read_record_idx(obj, seqnum + 1, &record_idx)) != LDB_OK)
            return rc;

        dat_end_new = record_idx.pos;
    }

    memset(&record_idx, 0x00, sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t));

    // set index entries to 0 (from top to down)
    while (seqnum < csn && obj->first_seqnum <= csn)
    {
        size_t pos = ldb_get_pos_idx(obj, csn);

        if (fseek(obj->idx_fp, (long) pos, SEEK_SET) != 0)
            return LDB_ERR_READ_IDX;

        if (fwrite(&record_idx, sizeof(ldb_record_idx_t), 1, obj->idx_fp) != 1)
            return LDB_ERR_WRITE_IDX;

        csn--;
    }

    if (fflush(obj->idx_fp) != 0)
        return LDB_ERR_WRITE_IDX;

    // update status
    if (seqnum < obj->first_seqnum) {
        obj->first_seqnum = 0;
        obj->first_timestamp = 0;
        obj->last_seqnum = 0;
        obj->last_timestamp = 0;
        obj->dat_end = sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t);
    }
    else {
        obj->last_seqnum = seqnum;
        obj->last_timestamp = last_timestamp_new;
        obj->dat_end = dat_end_new;
    }

    // set data entries to 0 (from down to top)
    if (!ldb_zeroize(obj->dat_fp, dat_end_new))
        return LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT;

    return removed_entries;
}

#define exit_function(errnum) do { ret = errnum; goto LDB_PURGE_END; } while(0)

int ldb_purge(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum)
{
    if (!ldb_is_valid_db(obj))
        return LDB_ERR;

    // case no entries to purge
    if (seqnum <= obj->first_seqnum || obj->first_seqnum == 0)
        return 0;

    int ret = LDB_ERR;
    int removed_entries = 0;
    ldb_record_idx_t record_idx = {0};
    ldb_record_dat_t record_dat = {0};
    char *tmp_path = NULL;
    FILE *tmp_fp = NULL;

    // case purge all entries
    if (obj->last_seqnum < seqnum)
    {
        removed_entries = obj->last_seqnum - obj->first_seqnum + 1;

        ldb_close_files(obj);

        remove(obj->dat_path);
        remove(obj->idx_path);

        if (!ldb_create_file_dat(obj->dat_path))
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_OPEN_DAT);

        if (!ldb_create_file_idx(obj->idx_path))
            exit_function(LDB_ERR_OPEN_IDX);

        if ((ret = ldb_open_file_dat(obj, false)) != LDB_OK)
            return ret;

        if ((ret = ldb_open_file_idx(obj, false)) != LDB_OK)
            return ret;

        return removed_entries;
    }

    // case purge some entries

    removed_entries = seqnum - obj->first_seqnum;

    if ((ret = ldb_read_record_idx(obj, seqnum, &record_idx)) != LDB_OK)
        return ret;

    size_t pos = record_idx.pos;

    if ((ret = ldb_read_record_dat(obj, pos, &record_dat)) != LDB_OK)
        return ret;

    if (record_dat.seqnum != seqnum)
        return LDB_ERR_FMT_IDX;

    tmp_path = ldb_create_filename(obj->path, obj->name, LDB_EXT_TMP);
    tmp_fp = fopen(tmp_path, "w");

    if (tmp_fp == NULL)
        return LDB_ERR_TMP_FILE;

    ldb_header_dat_t header = {
        .magic_number = LDB_MAGIC_NUMBER,
        .text = {0},
        .format = LDB_FORMAT_1,
        .milestone = 0
    };

    strncpy(header.text, LDB_TEXT_DAT, sizeof(header.text));

    if (fwrite(&header, sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t), 1, tmp_fp) != 1)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_TMP_FILE);

    if (!ldb_copy_file(obj->dat_fp, pos, obj->dat_end, tmp_fp, sizeof(ldb_header_dat_t)))
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_TMP_FILE);

    if (fclose(tmp_fp) != 0)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_TMP_FILE);

    if ((ret = ldb_close_files(obj)) != LDB_OK)
        goto LDB_PURGE_END;

    remove(obj->idx_path);

    if (rename(tmp_path, obj->dat_path) != 0)
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_TMP_FILE);

    if (!ldb_create_file_idx(obj->idx_path))
        exit_function(LDB_ERR_OPEN_IDX);

    if ((ret = ldb_open_file_dat(obj, false)) != LDB_OK)
        goto LDB_PURGE_END;

    if (( ret = ldb_open_file_idx(obj, false)) != LDB_OK)
        goto LDB_PURGE_END;

    free(tmp_path);
    return removed_entries;

LDB_PURGE_END:
    if (tmp_fp != NULL) fclose(tmp_fp);
    ldb_close_files(obj);
    free(tmp_path);
    return ret;
}

#undef exit_function

int ldb_update_milestone(ldb_db_t *obj, uint64_t seqnum)
{
    if (!ldb_is_valid_db(obj))
        return LDB_ERR;

    if (fseek(obj->dat_fp, offsetof(ldb_header_dat_t, milestone), SEEK_SET) != 0)
        return LDB_ERR_READ_DAT;

    if (fwrite(&seqnum, sizeof(uint64_t), 1, obj->dat_fp) != 1)
        return LDB_ERR_WRITE_DAT;

    obj->milestone = seqnum;

    return LDB_OK;
}

#undef LDB_FREE
#undef LDB_MIN
#undef LDB_MAX

#endif /* LDB_IMPL */


nit, typo: lenght ... lenght
Also, "it is rebuilT from the data",
and "reported as not writed" --> "written".
motivation
App developers who need logging features
would benefit from a brief comparison of packages.
There are other libraries they could use.
(Strawman: such as sqlite, or syslog.)
Help them understand where this library
is positioned in the broader ecosystem,
so they can evaluate whether it's a good fit.
file format
The (sequence, timestamp, length) tuple seems perfectly sensible.
Now imagine that a Bad Thing happened,
and random bytes get spewed across our datastructure,
either in RAM or on disk.
So both these record tuples and their associated payload data are corrupt.
I guess that restricted set of values on
those three could be used to identify the non-corrupt records?
I'm skeptical that it would be robust.
Consider incorporating a (prefix of) SHA3 or other checksum
into each record header, so you can make rock solid guarantees about
the non-corrupt portion of your DB.
Alternatively, consider writing a checksum log record
every now and again, to "lock in" the majority of the DB
as being demonstrably non-corrupt.
alignment
On some architectures alignment of integers matters,
and persisted logs may be read by multiple architectures.
The review context suggested that records
might start on random alignments.
But now I see ldb_allocated_size()
and it all looks good.
I'm glad to see you're explicit about C11 support,
and about using lcov + valgrind.
reuse of sequence numbers

We can access directly any record by seqnum because ...

It appears that after writing {6, 7, 8}, rollback(6),
we would write {7, 8} again.
Which is a little on the surprising side.
You might want to explicitly introduce the concept of a seqnum,
and describe its semantics.
For example, it turns out that zero cannot be a valid seqnum.
It also appears we have a hard invariant:
timestamps shall be in the same monotonic order as sequence numbers.
Again, being explicit wouldn't hurt.
For example, is it legit for record 7 and record 8
to have identical timestamp, due to having been
logged within timestamp granularity?
The milestone concept should be introduced, as well.
And consider listing it earlier in the header record,
before text.
operational advice
The requirement that there shall not be gaps
in the sequence numbers influences DevOps.
Hosts reboot, VMs come and go, nightly backups are made
and copied around the network,
planks in the
Ship of Theseus
are replaced.
Suppose I have a long-lived app which uses this log DB.
If I have been operating it for a hundred days
it has persisted quite a few records,
with only a subset being RAM resident.
Now I wish to do an OS upgrade,
replace a physical server,
create a hot-standby app server,
something like that.
We could use some guidance about
what sort of operations should be treated
as a "new" DB instance, contrasted with
operations that restore the "same" instance from storage.
unique id
I feel pretty strongly that we should roll
a new GUID each time a new DB instance is created,
and persist it in its header.
Then it's explicitly clear what a DevOps operation accomplishes.
Or we might view a pair of servers
that are "writing record seven"
as actually writing

(guid1, 7)
(guid2, 7)

Also, consider making LDB_MAGIC_NUMBER 64 bits long,
with part saying "ldb" and part looking more randomish.
name restriction
 * @param[in] name Database name (chars allowed: [a-ZA-Z_], max length = 32).

Prohibiting digits in a DB name seems odd.
OIC, in ldb_is_valid_name() we call isalnum(),
so this is just a documentation bug.
always fsync()




Data file is updated and flushed.




I predict that some users of this library
will wish optional flushing.
Common strategies include synchronously
flushing every N records or M milliseconds,
or having an async flush thread wakeup
every M milliseconds.
extra test
void ldb_free_entry(ldb_entry_t *entry)
{
    ...
    if (entry->metadata != NULL) {
        free(entry->metadata);
    }

Maybe skip the if, since
free()
will do the right thing with a NULL?

If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

CANT_REACH
static bool ldb_alloc_entry( ... )
{
        ...
        assert(false);

Recommend you find a better way to express "impossible!".
If you stick with assert, consider doing three of them,
one for each conjunct.
That would give a maintenance engineer more information
about what went south.
I like the "assert that lengths are aligned".
Similar code appears here:
static int ldb_append_record_idx( ... )
{
    ...
    if (record->seqnum != obj->last_seqnum) {
        assert(false);
        return LDB_ERR;

CWD
I guess you found a use case for this?
static bool ldb_is_valid_path(const char *path)
{
    ...
    if (*path == 0)  // case cwd (current working directory)
        return true;

But I would design a slightly more
restrictive Public API, which insists
on caller passing in ".".
Plus it's perfectly possible to chdir
someplace that's unreadable.
Recommend you just delete that test.
    if (access(path, R_OK) != 0)
        return false;

I don't understand that test.
It is somewhat common for a locked down daemon
to have execute permission on a directory, but not
read permission.
Which implies you must know the proper spelling
of a filename to access it, since you cannot scan for it.
Plus there's the usual
TOC/TOU
race nonsense.
Maybe this test lets us offer a more informative diagnostic?
But maybe it would be better to let a write error happen
when we actually write.
I am generally quite nervous about our reliance on access(),
plus on using F_OK rather than checking the actual
read or write permission we need.
Maybe we should document an intent to use this
code in a set-uid daemon?
An app could open a log, sleep for an hour,
then eventually write a record which fails.
So we might want to always log an "app started up!"
message upon opening the log,
just to force some immediate writing activity.
fstat()
ldb_get_file_size() is correct.
But it seems like a lot of work. We could just
fstat()
to learn the size.
ftell()
This codebase does an impressive job
of checking for error returns, almost always.
static int ldb_append_entry_dat( ... )
{
    ...
    obj->dat_end = (size_t) ftell(obj->dat_fp);

    return LDB_OK;

I wouldn't know how to provoke such behavior.
But I think the
man page
explains we might get back a -1?
In which case we should return an error.
special cases
I feel there are more special cases than necessary.
Consider insisting that a newly created LDB file
shall never be empty -- simply write a short "initialized!"
record upon creation.
Then we needn't worry about a well-formed file
having zero records.
Similarly, consider insisting that each appended record
has more than zero bytes.
extra undef
#undef exit_function
#define exit_function(errnum) do { ret = errnum; goto LDB_OPEN_FILE_IDX_END; } while(0)

I like the macro.
Recommend you elide the #undef, as we don't need it.
The other places we define it omit #undef,
and simply override any existing definition.
#undef LDB_FREE
#undef LDB_MIN
#undef LDB_MAX

Maybe you wanted to #undef exit_function at the end?

Thank you very much for your comments, I really appreciate it.
Definitively I will add the checksum in the record.

I see nothing C11-specific in your code, and it compiled just fine with gnu99 instead of gnu11. Though, I am going to suggest C11 features below.
Consider compiling with std=c11 and defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE and XOPEN_SOURCE to appropriate values. I don't see the need for enabling non-standard GNU extensions here.
Only include the header files that are required:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

From these, only stdio.h, stdbool.h, and stdint.h are needed for the function declarations. The rest of these should only be included when LBD_IMPL is defined by the client.
Additionally, C99 (N1256), C11 (N1570) and C17 (N2176) section 7.21.1 confirm that stdio.h declares size_t, so you don't need to include stddef.h along with stdio.h.
I also do not see anything from stdarg.h being used (I might be wrong here), so it can be elided.
Define the structures in the implementation:
I see no reason why the structure definitions should be available if the implementation is not included.
Prefer static inline functions to macros:
LDB_MAX() and LDB_MIN() aren't safe. Consider what happens when I do:
MAX(a++, b);

The code invokes undefined behavior, because a++ is expanded twice.
I did a quick search and found that you're using LDB_MAX() in two places, solely for type uint64_t, and LDB_MIN() in two places as well, solely for type long. Consider instead:
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER) 
    #define ATTRIB_INLINE    __attribute__((always_inline))
    #define ATTRIB_CONST     __attribute__((const))
#else
    #define ATTRIB_INLINE    /**/
    #define ATTRIB_CONST     /**/
#endif
    
ATTRIB_CONST ATTRIB_INLINE static inline max(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

ATTRIB_CONST ALWAYS_INLINE static inline min(long a, long b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

Now you get the both the type-safety, and assurance that passing something like a++ won't invoke undefined behavior.
But surely there are going to be changes in the future and other types would be used, in which case you should look into C11's _Generic. A quick Google search would bring up Jonathan Leffer's sample usage on StackOverflow with an implementation of a generic max() macro.
See also: Implications of pure and constant functions.

Allow clients to replace the standard memory allocation functions with custom ones:
Sometimes, I am using a custom arena allocator and do not want allocations to be done directly with the standard malloc() and family.
Consider:
#if defined(LDB_MALLOC) != defined(LDB_REALLOC) || defined(LDB_REALLOC) != defined(LDB_FREE)
    #error  "Must define all or none of LDB_MALLOC, LDB_REALLOC, and LDB_FREE."
#endif

#ifndef LDB_MALLOC
    #define LDB_MALLOC(sz)       malloc(sz)
    #define LDB_REALLOC(p, sz)   realloc(p, sz)
    #define LDB_FREE(p)          free(p)
#endif

This enables clients to do:
#define LDB_MALLOC(sz)     arena_alloc(sz)

before including your header, and does not restrict them by any means. But as you're only using calloc() (vim did not find any instances of malloc or realloc in this translation unit), you can only define LDB_CALLOC.
Similarly, you can allow clients to specify whether they want all functions to have internal linkage or not:
#ifndef LDB_DEF
    #ifdef LDB_STATIC
        #define LDB_DEF   static
    #else
        #define LDB_DEF   extern
    #endif                          /* LDB_STATIC */
#endif                              /* LDB_DEF */

Now I can do:
#define LDB_STATIC

before including the header to specify that all the functions should have internal linkage.
Typos:
default: return "Unknow error";

should be:
default: return "Unknown error";

In line 534:
"otherwhise" ==> "otherwise".
Same for line 719 and 776.
In line 716:
"zeroized" ==> "zeroed".
Same in line 752.
In line 1273:
"backard" ==> "backwards".
"rollbacked" ==> "rolled back".
In line 1389:
"ofending" ==> "offending".
Run spell on the codebase henceforth (set spell in Vim).
Put all error codes in an enum:
I am not pleased by seeing 20 macros, or negative error values, or by how the macro definitions are 300 lines away from the switch statement that returns the description of a particular error code. It is too easy to mess up, and you have to remember to make changes in two separate places.
If the error messages were the same as the macro names, we could have used X-macros, but as that's not possible, consider this pattern that I saw in Vim's codebase once:
static const char *const errors[] = {
#define ERROR_CODE_1
    [ERROR_CODE_1] = "error_code_1's description",
#define ERROR_CODE_2
    [ERROR_CODE_2] = "error_code_2's descriptions",
...

Or use an enum:
enum {
   LDB_OK,
   LDB_ERR,
   ...
}

// and an array of strings

And we can also add a compile time check (static_assert) to ensure that the the enum and the array of strings are in sync.
Using enumerated types instead of #defines is a good idea, if only because symbolic debuggers have those symbols available and can show them rather than raw integers.
The value of each subsequent enumerator is one greater than the previous enumerator:
So you can just do:
typedef enum {
    LDB_STATUS_CLOSED,
    LDB_STATUS_OPEN
} ldb_status_e;

instead of:
typedef enum {
    LDB_STATUS_CLOSED = 0,
    LDB_STATUS_OPEN = 1
} ldb_status_e;

Avoid unnecessary zeroing:
In ldb_is_valid_path():
    struct stat statbuf = {0};
    ...
    if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0)
        return false;

There's no need to zero-initialize statbuf when it is going overwritten in the call to stat().
I also do not see why everything needs to be set to 0 in the free..() functions.
Avoid prefixing identifiers with underscores in both C and C++:
All such identifiers are reserved for the implementation, in at least some contexts. Avoiding them altogether is better and easier than learning and remembering those specific contexts.
__LOGDB_H should be just LOGDB_H.
Unclear comments:
typedef enum {
    LDB_SEARCH_LOWER,        // Returns the seqnum of the first entry having timestamp not less than the given value.
    LDB_SEARCH_UPPER         // Returns the seqnum of the first entry having timestamp greater than the given value.
} ldb_search_e;

This might be a nitpick, but defining the values isn't exactly "returning" anything.
Make use of C99's new usage of static keyword:
Since C99, you can use the static keyword inside the [] operator in function parameters.
For instance:
bool foo(char bar[static 1]);

declares a function that expects a non-null argument of type char * that is pointing to at least one item.
This library's API would find this beneficial, as well as function attributes that are specific to GNU C (pure, const, malloc, nonnull, null_termianted_string, et cetera), but widely supported.
Do note that this would fail if you move the structure definitions to the implementation, because the C standard requires type T to be completed in any declaration of array type T[].
Check the return value of library functions:
According to the man page of gettimeofday():

gettimeofday() and settimeofday() return 0 for success.  On error, -1 is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.

But you've ignored its return value in ldb_get_millis().
The man page also says:

POSIX.1-2008 marks gettimeofday() as obsolete, recommending the use of clock_gettime(2) instead.

Switch to clock_gettime(2).
Similarly, in ldb_open(), the result of strdup() is ignored:
    obj->name = strdup(name);
    obj->path = strdup(path);

According to the man page:

On success, the strdup() function returns a pointer to the duplicated string.  It returns NULL if insufficient memory was available, with errno set to indicate the error.

Make use of C99's compound literals:
In ldb_free_entry() and others, you can replace assignments like:
    entry->metadata = NULL;
    entry->data = NULL;
    entry->metadata_len = 0;
    entry->data_len = 0;
}

with:
    *entry = (ldb_entry_t) {0};

You can also skip the NULL check before calling free(). If the argument passed to free() is a null pointer, it is basically a NOP.
Consider what happens when compiled for a release build:
If the code was compiled with -DNDEBUG, as it usually is for a release build, all the assertions would be disabled and half the error-checking would go out of the window.
Do not cast the result of malloc() and family:
Since the C89 standard, or about 35 years, malloc() and family have returned a generic void * that is implicitly converted to and from any other pointer type and does not require a cast. Casting is redundant and only serves to clutter the code.
This is different in C++, where there is no implicit conversion from a void *, and a cast is necessary. Though in C++, you'd be using something like reinterpret_cast.
So, this:
    ptr = (char *) calloc((len1 + len2)/sizeof(void *), sizeof(void *));

becomes:
    ptr = calloc((len1 + len2)/sizeof(void *), sizeof(void *));

Edit: I just saw #ifdef __cplusplus. You should keep the casts if this is to work with C++ too.
Merge consecutive conditions:
if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0) {
    return false;
}

if (!S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
    return false;
}

if (access(path, R_OK) != 0) {
    return false;
}

becomes:
if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0
    || !S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)
    || access(path, R_OK) != 0) {
    return false;
}

Use C11's new x file opening mode and avoid TOC/TOU bugs:
I see some patterns like:

Check if file exists with access().
If it does, return false.
If it doesn't, call fopen() and create the file.

Consider what happens if the file gets created before the call to access() and fopen():

File is created and perhaps written to.
fopen() successfully opens it with the w mode and destroys it.
Client (perhaps a malicious user) loses a precious file and your library is responsible for overwriting it.

Instead, I'd suggest adding the x mode in the second argument to fopen():
FILE *fp = fopen(path, "wx");

According to the documentation:

File access mode flag "x" can optionally be appended to "w" or "w+" specifiers. This flag forces the function to fail if the file exists, instead of overwriting it. (C11)

And as I see some calls with the update +, keep in mind that:

In update mode ('+'), both input and output may be performed, but output cannot be followed by input without an intervening call to fflush, fseek, fsetpos or rewind, and input cannot be followed by output without an intervening call to fseek, fsetpos or rewind, unless the input operation encountered end of file. In update mode, implementations are permitted to use binary mode even when text mode is specified.

Do not try to determine the size of any file with fseek() and ftell():
You've fallen into the usual trap of using fseek() and ftell(), for which I don't blame you, because this is what the top answers for "How to find the size of a file in C" suggest on StackOverflow. (Now if only people would scroll downwards too.)
The fseek() and ftell() functions are both defined by the ISO C language standard. The following is from the public latest draft of the C2X standard:
7.23.9.2:

The fseek function sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream. If a read or write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and fseek fails.


For a binary stream, the new position, measured in characters from the beginning of the file, is obtained by adding offset to the position specified by whence. The specified position is the beginning of the file if whence is SEEK_SET, the current value of the file position indicator if SEEK_CUR, or end-of-file if SEEK_END. A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END.

A footnote below "7.23.4.2 The rename function" also states:

Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial shift state.

As a binary stream need not support SEEK_END, you can not rely on it.
There's no portable away to find the size of a file in C, except for reading the whole file. POSIX's stat()/fstat() is another option, which are implemented by Windows as well (as _fstat() and _stat(), with around 10 different versions, as far as I can remember), and are pretty portable.
Even for ordinary text files, there's no guarantee that ftell() returns the actual byte count, so you can't depend on it.
Simplify:
static char * ldb_create_filename(const char *path, const char *name, const char *ext)
{
    if (path == NULL || name == NULL || ext == NULL || strlen(name) == 0)
        return NULL;

    size_t len = strlen(path);
    bool path_sep_required = (len > 0 && path[len -1] != LDB_PATH_SEPARATOR[0]);

    len = strlen(path) + 1 + strlen(name) + strlen(ext) + 1;
    char *filepath = (char *) calloc(len, sizeof(char));

    if (filepath == NULL)
        return NULL;

    snprintf(filepath, len, "%s%s%s%s", 
             path,
             (path_sep_required ? LDB_PATH_SEPARATOR : ""),
             name,
             ext);

    return filepath;
}

You need not call strlen() to check if a string is empty. Simply do:
if (*name == '\0')

But if you're going to do so, cache it so you would not have to call it again.
Though, I see no reason why you used strlen(path) twice in assignments to len.
static char * ldb_create_filename(const char *path, const char *name, const char *ext)
{
    if (path == NULL || name == NULL || ext == NULL || *name == '\0') {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t len = strlen(path);
    bool path_sep_required = (len > 0 && path[len -1] != LDB_PATH_SEPARATOR[0]);
    len += 1 + strlen(name) + strlen(ext) + 1;
    char *filepath = (char *) calloc(len, 1);

    if (filepath != NULL) {
        snprintf(filepath, len, "%s%s%s%s", 
             path,
             (path_sep_required ? LDB_PATH_SEPARATOR : ""),
             name,
             ext);
    }
    return filepath;
}

Also note that sizeof(char) is defined by the standard to be 1, so you can safely elide it.
Prefer BUFSIZ from stdio.h to similar custom buffer sizes:
The value of BUFSIZ is chosen on each system so as to make stream I/O efficient. So it is a good idea to use BUFSIZ as the size for the buffer when doing any I/O. Consider changing 4096 to BUFSIZ.
Also, for copying files, look into non-standard sendfile()/fcopyfile() and fall back to the default method when they're not present. (You can determine it by checking for pre-defined macros. A quick google search would bring up some StackOverflow answer showing how to check for Linux or FreeBSD et cetera.)
It is defined as 8096 on my system, though it might be a good idea use something as big as 64 KiB.
Too much code for one sitting. Perhaps more later. Thank you for the tests, they are very reassuring. It is refreshing to see a header only testing library too, I had gotten tired of libcriterion. Do try AddressSanitizer + StaticAnalyzer. I added -Wconversion to the Makefile and it spouted a lot of warnings like "conversion from size_t to uint32_t" in calls to strlen() et cetera. These should be fixed. Consider using an automatic code formatter too (GNU Indent, clang-format, Astyle et cetera).

Thank you for your comments.
I take most of them into consideration.
I have also learned new things (ex. inline directives).
